# How can i join two tables and return rows with does not match. In sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I have Two Tables Table1 and Table 2 with 3 columns id,name and mac address and in second table I also have column named mac.

The things I need that in table 1 I have 10 records and in table 2 I have only 5 records and I want the records which are not present in table2.

How can I do this in sqlite android? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance...

Thanks for making a time to read this

In Table name I am adding a name from second class

this query is for sql and i need for sqlite

```
SELECT T1.*
FROM T1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL
                     FROM T2
                     WHERE T1.ID = T2.ID 
                         AND T1.Date = T2.Date
                         AND T1.Hour = T2.Hour)
```

Comment: I'm not tried it by myself, so could you try : `SELECT T1.*
FROM T1
LEFT JOIN T2 on T1.ID = T2.ID AND T1.Date = T2.Date AND T1.Hour = T2.Hour
WHERE T2.ID is null`

Comment: I AM adding a table name from second class?

Comment: i have no idea what is the second class, here the question is about how to rewrite sql, i suppose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work with SQLite, albeit not efficiently.

If ID does what it should do, then checking for T1.Date = T2.Date and T1.Hour = T2.Hour could be left out.

Better way using JOIN:

```
SELECT T1.*
FROM T1
LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
WHERE T2.ID IS NULL;
```

Comment: in this query i can get the tablename from another class na like Select id,name from mainactivity.collect where main activity is my class name and collect is an string variable can i do this ?

Comment: @Badprince You seem to confuse your Java and SQL. I am unsure what you want to say: If you mean that you would like to give tables, columns or values or something else in your database the same name like the name you gave to your android activity, that is clearly possible. Why not?

Comment: the qures will be like this sqlite.rawquery(SELECT T1.*
FROM T1
LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
WHERE T2.ID IS NULL); ???

Comment: I am not too sure but I think that _rawQuery_ takes at least two arguments... Try adding an argument with type _String[]_. (For example write _new String[]_.)

Comment: Okay Thank you so much for making a time :)

Comment: sqLiteDatabase.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { name, mac },null, null, null,null, null);

Comment: i am using this query how can i add that query in this query ??

Comment: View https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html and have a look at _query_ in the public methods section. I have not tried it myself but it could be possible to implement the _JOIN_ using the table name argument. However it seems that _rawQuery_ fits much better.

Answer (score 0):

you specify the condition based on reference key (I assumed MAC)

```
Select T1.ID, T1.Name From Table1 T1 LEFT JOIN From Table2 T2 on T1.Mac=T2.Mac where T2.Mac is NULL.
```

or

```
SELECT id, name 
FROM Table2 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT * 
     FROM Table2 
     WHERE Table1.Mac = Table2.Mac)
```

Comment: in this query i can get the tablename from another class na like Select id,name from mainactivity.collect where main activity is my class name and collect is an string variable can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
  FROM T1
  WHERE T1.name NOT IN (SELECT name FROM T2 )
```

-------------------Or do this for more restriction--------------------------

```
SELECT *
  FROM T1
  WHERE T1.name NOT IN (SELECT name FROM T2 ) and
        T1.mac NOT IN  (SELECT mac FROM T2 )
```